# Why it is uploading only 1 photo of 3 and database doesn't get all fields?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

I create an android app using Firebase and I do have 3 buttons for uploading 3 different images. But when I submit the request it upload the third image 3 times, and in the database some fields are missing. Let me show you what I did:

This is the User Model:

```
public class CarrierUser {


    public String fullname;
    public String email;
    public String password;
    public String address;
    public String city;
    public String state;
    public String zipcode;
    public String country;
    public String phone;

    public String cardnumber;
    public String expiredate;
    public String CVC;
    public String rate;
    public String type;
    public String profilePic;
    public String idPic;
    public String criminalRecordPic;
    public Boolean activated;

    public CarrierUser() {

    }

    public CarrierUser(String fullname, String email, String password, String address, String city, String state, String zipcode, String country, String phone, String cardnumber, String expiredate, String CVC, String type, String rate, String profilePic, String idPic, String criminalRecordPic, Boolean activated) {
        this.fullname = fullname;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.address = address;
        this.city = city;
        this.state = state;
        this.zipcode = zipcode;
        this.country = country;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.cardnumber = cardnumber;
        this.expiredate = expiredate;
        this.CVC = CVC;
        this.type = type;
        this.rate = rate;
        this.profilePic = profilePic;
        this.idPic = idPic;
        this.criminalRecordPic = criminalRecordPic;
        this.activated = activated;
    }
}
```

And this is the Signup Class, I know it is a lot to read, but I really need help.

```
public class SignupCarrier extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText editfullname, editemail, editpassword, editconfirmpassword, editaddress, editcity, editstate, editzipcode, editcountry, editphone, editcardnumber, editexpiredate, editcvc;
Button upProfile, upIDPhoto, upCriminalRecord, buttonSigningUp;
private Uri mProfilePic, mIdPhoto,mCriminalRecord;
FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;
    String finalPath;
private StorageReference mStorageRef;
private StorageTask mUploadTask;
    private static final int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST_PROFILE = 1;
    private static final int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST_ID = 1;
    private static final int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST_CR = 1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup_carrier);

        editfullname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fullname);
        editemail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        editpassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        editconfirmpassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.confirmpassword);
        editaddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.address);
        editcity = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.city);
        editstate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.state);
        editzipcode = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.zipcode);
        editcountry = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.country);
        editphone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phone);



        editcardnumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cardnumber);
        editexpiredate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.expiredate);
        editcvc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cvc);

        mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        upProfile = (Button) findViewById(R.id.profilePic);
        upIDPhoto = (Button) findViewById(R.id.idphotoPic);
        upCriminalRecord = (Button) findViewById(R.id.criminalRecord);
        buttonSigningUp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSigningUp);
        mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("carriersPictures");

        upProfile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openFileChooser(mProfilePic);
            }
        });
        upIDPhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openFileChooser(mIdPhoto);
            }
        });
        upCriminalRecord.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openFileChooser(mCriminalRecord);
            }
        });

        buttonSigningUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final String profilePictUri = uploadFile(mProfilePic);
                final String idPictUri = uploadFile(mIdPhoto);
                final String criminalRecordUri = uploadFile(mCriminalRecord);
                final String fullname = editfullname.getText().toString();
                final String email = editemail.getText().toString();
                final String password = editpassword.getText().toString();
                final String confirmPassword = editconfirmpassword.getText().toString();
                final String address = editaddress.getText().toString();
                final String city = editcity.getText().toString();
                final String state = editstate.getText().toString();
                final String zipcode = editzipcode.getText().toString();
                final String country = editcountry.getText().toString();
                final String phone = editphone.getText().toString();
                final String rate = "0";
                final String type = "carrier";
                final String cardnumber = editcardnumber.getText().toString();
                final String expiredate = editexpiredate.getText().toString();
                final String CVC = editcvc.getText().toString();
                String s = "none";
                if(fullname.isEmpty()) {
                    editfullname.setError("enter a valid fullname");
                    editfullname.requestFocus();
                    return;

                }
                if(email.isEmpty()) {
                    editemail.setError("enter a valid email");
                    editemail.requestFocus();
                    return;
                }
                if(password.isEmpty()) {
                    editpassword.setError("enter a valid password");
                    editpassword.requestFocus();
                    return;
                }
                if(confirmPassword.isEmpty()) {
                    editconfirmpassword.setError("this should not be empty");
                    editconfirmpassword.requestFocus();
                    return;
                }
                if(address.isEmpty()) {
                    editaddress.setError("enter a valid address");
                    editaddress.requestFocus();
                    return;
                }
                if(city.isEmpty()) {
                    editcity.setError("enter a valid city ");
                    editcity.requestFocus();
                    return;
                }
                if(state.isEmpty()) {
                    editstate.setError("enter a valid state/region");
                    editstate.requestFocus();
                    return;
                }
                if(zipcode.isEmpty()) {
                    editzipcode.setError("enter a valid zipcode");
                    editzipcode.requestFocus();
                    return;
                }
                if(country.isEmpty() ) {
                    editcountry.setError("enter a valid country");
                    editcountry.requestFocus();
                    return;
                }

                if(phone.isEmpty()) {
                    editphone.setError("enter a valid phone");
                    editphone.requestFocus();
                    return;
                }


                if(password.length() < 8){
                    editpassword.setError("password should be at least 8 characters long");
                    editpassword.requestFocus();
                    return;
                }
                if(!password.equals(confirmPassword)) {
                    editconfirmpassword.setError("passwords don't match");
                    editconfirmpassword.requestFocus();
                    return;
                }

                if(cardnumber.isEmpty()) {
                    editcardnumber.setError("enter a valid card number");
                    editcardnumber.requestFocus();
                    return;

                }

                if(expiredate.isEmpty())
                {
                    editexpiredate.setError("enter a valid expired date ");
                    editexpiredate.requestFocus();
                }
                if(CVC.isEmpty())
                {
                    editcvc.setError("enter a valid CVC ");
                    editcvc.requestFocus();
                }
                final boolean activated = false;
                mFirebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                            CarrierUser carrierUser = new CarrierUser(
                                    fullname,
                                    email,
                                    password,
                                    address,
                                    city,
                                    state,
                                    zipcode,
                                    country,
                                    phone,
                                    cardnumber,
                                    expiredate,
                                    CVC,
                                    type,
                                    rate,
                                    profilePictUri,
                                    idPictUri,
                                    criminalRecordUri,
                                    activated

                            );
                            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User")
                                    .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).setValue(carrierUser).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                    if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                                        Toast.makeText(SignupCarrier.this,"Your request has been sent for approval", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        openLogin();
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });



            }
        });

    }

    private void openLogin() {
        Intent i = new Intent(SignupCarrier.this, screenNotLogged.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
    private  String getFileExtension(Uri uri) {
        ContentResolver cR = getContentResolver();
        MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        return mime.getExtensionFromMimeType(cR.getType(uri));
    }
    private String uploadFile(Uri path) {

        if(path != null) {

            StorageReference fileReference = mStorageRef.child(editfullname.getText().toString()+"-"+System.currentTimeMillis()+getFileExtension(path));
            mUploadTask = fileReference.putFile(path)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            finalPath = taskSnapshot.getUploadSessionUri().toString();
                        }
                    })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(SignupCarrier.this, e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }
        return finalPath;
    }
    private void openFileChooser( Uri urltoPhoto) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        if (urltoPhoto == mProfilePic) {
            startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST_PROFILE);
        } else if (urltoPhoto == mIdPhoto) {
            startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST_ID);
        } else if (urltoPhoto == mCriminalRecord) {
            startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST_CR);
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST_PROFILE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null)
        {
            mProfilePic = data.getData();


        }
        if(requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST_ID && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null)
        {
            mIdPhoto = data.getData();


        }
        if(requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST_CR && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null)
        {
            mCriminalRecord = data.getData();


        }
    }
}
```

Since I need the URLs of the uploaded files I considered to declare some variables equal to the function that upload that image to the database, and make that function return a String, it seemed logic. 
I think the profilePic, idPic and criminalRecordPic fields are missing because that logic didn't work and that function didn't return the string I needed, but the question is, how can I get those URLs?

I would appreciate if you can help me! Thank you!

Comment: Use Arrays to store URIs

Comment: oh okay, thank you

Comment: don't forget to vote up if it was helpful ;)

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **330** lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.